# Value of doReturn not used

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, powermock

I use spring boot 2. 
I search to test a private method in the facade

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SamplingsFacadeTest {

    @Autowired
    private SamplingsFacade facade;

    @MockBean
    private SamplingsService samplingsService;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {

        List<Samplings> samplings = new ArrayList<>();
        Samplling sampling = new Samplings();
        ..
        samplings.add(sampling);

        //fake call
        Mockito.doReturn(samplings).when(samplingsService.getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest());

        //real call
        List<FactoryEmailNCDto> factoryEmails = Whitebox.invokeMethod(facade, "prepareDataNoncompliantSampling");

    }

public List<Samplings> getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest() {

    return samplingsRepository.findSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest();
}
```

In Facade In

```
private List<FactoryEmailNCDto> prepareDataNoncompliantSampling() {

    List<FactoryEmailNCDto> factoryEmailNC = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Samplings> samplings = samplingsService.getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest();

    for (Samplings sampling : samplings) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Why when I debug, samplings is null and not the value I created

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.doReturn(samplings)
    .when(samplingsService.getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest());
```

One potential problem is that `doReturn` takes the form `doReturn(value).when(mock).method()`, not `doReturn(value).when(mock.method())`. The latter is considered an incomplete stubbing. Instead, it should look like this:

```
Mockito.doReturn(samplings)
    .when(samplingsService)
    .getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest();
```

Note that there may be other problems with your test; the code you've written expects `samplingsService` to be `public` and non-`final`, and your `getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest()` to likewise be `public`, non-`static`, and non-`final`, but the code sample you have does not confirm that. You may want to call `Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()` in an `@After` method, or use [a `@Rule` that handles Mockito annotations and cleanup for you](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html).

Comment: getSamplingContainingNonCompliantTest is public, samplingsService is public and non final. I tried Mockito.validateMockitoUsage() in a after, no fail